# How did we derive the least square estimator using OLS?

Tags: least-squares, matrix, estimators, derivative

[image: ols]

1. How does multiplying a matrix with its transpose equal "minimizing" it?
2. When calculating the partial derivative, where does the X' come from?
3. Why setting the value of third equation to 0 is legal here and why did the X' changed again to W' in the third equation?

Answer (score 1):

$\bullet$ Multiplying a matrix with its transpose doesn't "minimise" it. Here, we seek $\bf a$ such that sum of squares of residuals i.e. $\boldsymbol\epsilon^\top\boldsymbol\epsilon$ gets minimised.

$\bullet$ That is plausibly a typo.

$\bullet  $ The derivative has to be equated to zero in order to meet the first order condition: remember we are seeking to **minimise** the residual sum of squares.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What do you mean by the word minimise? To make it close to zero?

Comment: Please check what it means to [minimise a function](https://mathinsight.org/minimization_maximization_refresher).